# How to do a PUT request with jQuery / Axios? It always returns error 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios, put

To begin with, how can I do a PUT request in JavaScript? (for context, I'm developing a Vue app)
The same request In postman or any rest client works perfectly, and I found that the problem Is that the Api expects the body to be `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` but sending It through Javascript just send It In plain JSON or not In a format understandable by the API.

I tried: `$.put("...")` but It returns function not found.
I tried a basic Ajax call with `type / _method = "put"`  but It doesn't work either because the content sent do not match.

What does the API expect?

```
person: {info: {name: "--", surname: "---"}}
location: {info: {city: "--", postalc: "---"}}
ref: 1234
```

How I'm sending it?

```
JSON.stringify({
person: {info: {name: "--", surname: "---"}}
location: {info: {city: "--", postalc: "---"}}
ref: 1234
})
```

Or

```
$.param(({
person: {info: {name: "--", surname: "---"}}
location: {info: {city: "--", postalc: "---"}}
ref: 1234
})
```

Request example with Axios:

```
const res = axios.put(
              "http://" + api + "/sendClientInfo/",
              {
                $.param(({
                person: {info: {name: "--", surname: "---"}}
                location: {info: {city: "--", postalc: "---"}}
                ref: 1234
                }),
              },
              {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
              }
            );
```

Example with jQuery

```
$.ajax("http://" + api + "/sendClientInfo/", {
              type: "PUT",
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              contentType: "application/json",
              success: function () {
                console.log("exit");
              },
```

Comment: That's a truly bizarre request payload requirement. Why not just go JSON for the whole thing?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the API expect?
>
> ```
> person: {info: {name: "--", surname: "---"}}
> location: {info: {city: "--", postalc: "---"}}
> ref: 1234
> ```

To me, this looks like the API expects 3 `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters with the first two holding JSON values.

To achieve that, you'd want something like this

```js
const person = { info: { name: "--", surname: "---" } }
const location = { info: { name: "--", surname: "---" } }
const data = {
  person: JSON.stringify(person), // encode these values as JSON
  location: JSON.stringify(location),
  ref: 1234
}

const url = `http://${api}/sendClientInfo/`

// jQuery
$.ajax({
  url,
  method: "PUT",
  data
})

// Axios
axios.put(url, new URLSearchParams(data))
```

jQuery's default data payload format is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Objects are encoded via the [`$.param()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

Axios will also use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if presented with a `URLSearchParams` data instance. This does the same thing as `$.param()`

Both payloads will be encoded as

```
person=%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22--%22%2C%22surname%22%3A%22---%22%7D%7D&location=%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22city%22%3A%22--%22%2C%22postalc%22%3A%22---%22%7D%7D&ref=1234
```

Comment: You are literally insane man, I spent almost two days trying to figure It out and you just did It In a pair of seconds. It works!! Thanks you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be on to the API developers immediately about their expected request payloads